# Counting error in C++

Tags: c++, matrix

I am writing a program to output the transpose of a matrix. The program works when I use it on matrices which are square or have more columns than rows, but gives the wrong output when I try to use it on matrices with more rows than columns.

The jist of the program is it reads in the numbers to a vector, then push this vector onto the 2D vector `data`. This part of the code works fine (as far as I can tell), I think the error is in these loops

```
if (data[0].size() < data.size()) // number of columns < number of rows BREAKS
{ // test52 gets here
for(size_t i=0; i<data[0].size(); ++i) // loops over the number of rows
{
  for(size_t j=0; j<data.size(); ++j) // loops over the number of columns (the number of entries in each row)
  {
    cout << data[j][i] << "\t";
  }
  cout << endl;
}
```

}

If I run this with the matrix

```
1,2
3,4
5,6
7,8
9,10
```

the output is `1 3 5 7 9`, so it's missing out the second column.

I'm getting no errors when I compile and run. I've been staring at the code for over an hour now and for the life of me I can't figure out whats going wrong.

Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT**

Sorry everyone, the program works fine. The problem was that I was trying to make the program read a text file in the wrong format (I forgot the commas)!

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Run in a debugger, step through the code line by line, watch the variables (especially `data[i]` versus `data[j]`).

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
i<data[i].size();
```

with

```
i<data[0].size();
```

Comment: just tried it, the program gave the same output as before

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
for(size_t i=0; i<=data[0].size(); ++i) // loops over the number of rows
```

should be this:

```
for(size_t i=0; i<data[0].size(); ++i) // loops over the number of rows
```

You are iterating past the end of the vector and getting **undefined behavior**.